# How to check if an address interacted with a specific contract in Ethereum network?

Tags: transactions

How can I check if an address interacted with a given contract in the ethreum network?

Is that possible?

If yes how can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Inside the contract being called?

Comment: no, inside the adress that called the contract?

Comment: is there any difference between the two cases ?